# How to create an online database for an android app?

Tags: java, android, sql, database

How can I make an online database for an android app?

I am making an android app about the impressive speech and I want to make a database storing accounts of users so they can retrieve their progress anytime anywhere. But how can I make it online so it is accessible from every device?

Comment: You're going to need more than a database for that. You need a whole API. Without an API, you can't retreive data, execute statement, validate user input and doing some calculation. I suggest looking into REST api as it is the standart right now. You could look for REST API framework in a language you know and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a service such as [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) or write a backend-server which runs a database (for example using Spring Boot and a simple H2 database would solve it).

Comment: Can I post the database in Internet (encrypt everything first) and then get it from the code as an object and get the information from the object?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "post it to the internet"? If I understand correctly, you want to store a file (= database ) and upload it somewhere and get it for each user? This creates several problems, like what do you do if two user update at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution for your problem is to use Firebase and especially Firebase Database.
Another solution is to use Parse Server.